# Selenium locating elements by more than one method

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium to locate elements in a page. Is there any way to combine two methods together?
Example:

Method 1: driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text('html')

Method 2: driver.find_elements_by_class_name('iUh30')

I will ideally like a method that finds elements that has both the partial link text and class name specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xpath to combine both selectors:

`driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='iUh30'][text()[contains(.,'html')]]")`

The `//*` looks for any element with any tag. Might be `<a>`, might be `<div>`, `<input>`, anything. You can just change it to the desired tag.

The above find the element by **exact** class name. You can also use `[contains(@class, 'partial_class')]` to find elements by partial class.

The `[text()[contains(.,'html')]]` looks for elements which **partial** text is "html"

Comment: please correct me if I'm wrong, 'text' is different from 'link_text'. In the first instance, the method will look to see if the displayed/visible link contains the 'text' while the latter method will look to see if the link (even if not completely displayed/visible) contains the 'text'

Comment: `partial link text` find the element even if the link is not visible. All selectors look for elements which are present in the `DOM`. To check their visibility we use `is_displayed()` method.

Comment: @user1783739 and to make sure you look for links use `<a>` tag instead of `*` like this: `//a[@class...`

Comment: You can (and should) reduce `[text()[contains(.,'html')]]` to `[contains(.,'html')]`. Also, link text requires an `A` tag so your `//*` should be `//a` to meet OP's requirements.

Comment: @user1783739 `text` is the text that is contained in the element. `link_text` is just `text` but specifically for an `A` tag. So if you are looking at an `A` tag, `link_text` and `text` are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture all class containing **iUh30** use following xpath

```
//*[contains(@class,'iUh30')] | //*[text()[contains(.,'html')]]
```

else if you want only elements that have exact text **iUh30** in classes

```
//*[@class='iUh30'] | //*[text()[contains(.,'html')]]
```